# Recording Audio with background sound is out of sync when played back with the sound

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder, avmutablecomposition

What i am trying to achieve is making a sort of a karaoke application that will play music in the background while the user sings. With headphones everything seems to work fine but when i try to record and merge audio files when on speaker, i am facing some syncing issues.

I play an audio file and immediately start recording. After the recording is done, i play both the recorded audio file and original soundtrack back simultaneously and what seems to be happening is that there is a slight delay between the audio of both the files when played via `AVAudioPlayer` (This problem doesn't appear when using headphones as the recorded audio doesn't have the music playing in the background from the speaker port).

I have tried using [SCRecorder](https://github.com/rFlex/SCRecorder) to record the file (as i have to merge videos as well) and using just `AVAudioRecorder` both and there is a slight delay in both the cases. Normally you wouldn't be able to tell but I have to play the recording and original file simultaneously so it appears to have an echo. Since the audio has quite a lot of beats it appears quite out of tune as well.

Also if i merge all the files starting from the 0th second using `AVMutableComposition`, there is still a delay which leads me to believe that the recording itself has a delay, even though i start the `record` and `play` methods simultaneously:

```
func startRecording(){
    audioPlayer.play()
    videoRecorder?.record()
    delegate?.didStartRecording()
}
//prepareToRecord has been called way before during initialization of the class
```

Now the problem is solved if i forcefully add a delay of 0.1 seconds for playbacks everywhere but i'd rather really know the reason as to what can be causing this issue and figure out a solution.